# High profile MonoTouch apps?

Tags: iphone, app-store, xamarin.ios

I would like some examples of high profile apps created using MonoTouch. The apps you call home about. The apps that made it to the top 25 lists in their category.

Where can I find examples of such applications?

This is a valid question, and should be re-opened. I need concrete examples of good applications developed using MonoTouch, in order to motivate why MonoTouch should be considered for client projects.

Comment: http://monotouch.info/MonoTouch/Apps

Comment: @Jason: It is a comprehensive list, but do not answer my question. By browsing all apps on the first page it is obvious that no app will be used to "impress my friends", with the exception of iCircuit. So where are the MonoTouch apps I can use to impress my friends?