# High profile MonoTouch apps?

Tags: iphone, app-store, xamarin.ios

A client do not want to consider MonoTouch for a new project.

[MonoTouch.info](http://monotouch.info/MonoTouch/Apps) has a long list of apps, but I have not found any on the caliber that can convince a client too choose a technology. The client has seen the list, and actually use the bland screenshots as an argument against MonoTouch.

Where can I find examples of applications useful as motivation. High profile apps created using MonoTouch, the apps you call home about. The apps that made it to the top 25 lists in their category.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [High profile MonoTouch apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016043/high-profile-monotouch-apps)

Comment: what kind of apps are you looking for? Games? Enterprise apps?

Comment: @Brad: Not possibly, it is. But my I guess my first attempt was too vaguely worded on the intention of the question. So some MonoTouch devs took it as an attempt to flame I guess, and voted for it to be closed.

Comment: @Eduardo: Any kind of application that is a shining jewel. Target audience does not matter, just that the app can be used to "impress my friends".

Comment: I don't know that it was regarded as a hostile question, but that people closed it because it was a poll or list-based question with no definitive answer.  I've seen a number of those closed for other "high-profile [language] applications" questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I responded on Twitter but thought I'd reply properly here;

The first app I will mention is iCircuit - http://icircuitapp.com/ - this application is featured on the Apple website here - http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/apps/index.html#workflow-icircuit - and is a pretty good seller.

Diggify is a Digg application which hit the top #8 sold application in Canada apparently - http://www.intomobile.com/apps/diggify/359756952/

An application that I built myself (it's a little old now admittedly) but I do think that it looks rather nice - http://bit.ly/gfxmasappstore :)

London Bike App is another nice looking application - http://www.londonbikeapp.com/

**Update:** Wow, this is an old question, there's a whole bunch of great apps using MonoTouch at http://xamarin.com/apps

Hope this helps,

ChrisNTR

Comment: Sorry for not replying on Twitter. It is a good start, thanks.

Comment: I can't quite work out what exactly you're looking for. If one MonoTouch application can do X then potentially all MonoTouch applications can do X. Just because it hasn't been done doesn't mean the potential is not there. :)

Comment: The client argues that MonoTouch while accessing the same API in itself is an obstacle for creating great apps. I want to argue that only the skill of the developer is a problem, not MonoTouch in itself. But it is hard argue when the majority of apps known to be made with MonoTouch in all honesty are crappy, or bland at best.

Answer (score 4):

I know of a couple apps that were built using Monotouch and sold very well but due to the uncertainly surrounding the terms when MT first came out and later the 3.3.1 mess the devs didn't make a big fuss out of it.  I suspect they aren't the only ones not publicizing what technology they used to make their app.

If your client is using a handful of screenshots on a website as the reason to rule out using Monotouch then you might want to rethink your pitch.  Whether or not an app has been developed in native Objective-C or C# via Monotouch makes no difference on the overall design or appearance because both rely on the CocoaTouch framework for UI.  Being able to deliver an app that meets your client's idea of what makes a great app has nothing to do with the language you use and has everything to do with your ability to translate the essence of their ideas into a solid design and UX.  Sell that, not the framework.

Comment: I understand you point. But the client argument is along the same lines; "Both use the same API, so why are MonoTouch apps so bland?". I need examples to show that the blandness is not due to MonoTouch, but due to the crappy devs. Or I need a new pitch as you say, I am open for ideas.

Comment: Many of the MonoTouch developers that write those apps are here in stackoverflow, answering questions like this one. Saying that most of them are crappy is really not the most sane way of asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

I found this article to be helpful when I'm trying to explain to others why I use Monotouch over native objective-c.

["Why we chose MonoTouch to write the Diggify iPhone app"](http://simon.nureality.ca/simon-says-why-we-chose-monotouch-to-write-the-diggify-iphone-app/)